# RewriteRule and GET

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I try to redirect:
from: www.myDomain.com/ca/blog/first-post
to: www.myDomain/ca/blog/post.php?url=first-post

I write this in the .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^ca\/blog\/(.*)\/?$  ca/blog/post.php?url=$1 [L]
```

In post.php I have this:

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
echo $url;
```

It seems that it goes to the right file: post.php, but the echo gives:
post.php and it should give first-post (or whatever I have after blog/)

I have tested the regex pattern here: http://regexr.com/3c5ud and it is ok

I have tested also the htaccess here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be

But when I put in the server still gives post.php. Can anyone explain, please.

In the .htaccess I have other rules:

```
# Get rid of .php :
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# Page of errors:
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/noTrobat.html

# From no www to yes www :
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: The page is `post.php` or the echo is `post.php`?

Comment: The problem is that the pattern also matches post.php itself, and is easily corrected. But I suspect you have more rewrite rules in the .htaccess, because this would usually cause a rewrite loop and 500 error. Please post anything else in the .htaccess file so we can recommend the correct solution.

Comment: @chris85 I want the RewriteRule drive me to www.myDomain/ca/blog/post.php?url=first-post  or what I have after blog/

Comment: Please show full .htacces file so we can see where the rewrite rule in question is located relative to the other rules you have shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your current rule matches `post.php`, as well. So, you get this:

```
www.myDomain.com/ca/blog/first-post
  ->  www.myDomain/ca/blog/post.php?url=first-post
     ->  www.myDomain/ca/blog/post.php?url=post.php
```

Add a rule before your current rule, to prevent rewriting of `post.php` itself:

```
RewriteRule ^ca\/blog\/post\.php - [L]
RewriteRule ^ca\/blog\/(.*)\/?$  ca/blog/post.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I works. Thank you. You put a dash before [L]  Does it mean: "not match this"  Can you explain please?

Comment: @Nrc Glad it helped! Please remember to accept the answer. :) The `-` before the `[L]` simply means "don't change it; leave it alone."